# Rsyslog not capturing Remote log

Tags: centos6, rsyslog

I am on the way to configure LogAnalyzer with Rsyslog server. I am all done with HTTP configuration. 
but my loganalyzer is only logging logs from localhost. I am little bit confused that where to configure snmp string/community. eventhough i check on MYSql but there is no logs from my cisco devices.

please help me.

```
# Provides TCP syslog reception
# for parameters see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imtcp.html
module(load="imtcp") # needs to be done just once
input(type="imtcp" port="514")

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  /var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log




 $ModLoad ommysql
 *.* :ommysql:127.0.0.1,Syslog,Syslogadmin,123456

#allow logs sender’s IP range below below
$AllowedSender UDP, 10.50.56.34
$AllowedSender TCP, 10.50.56.34
```

Comment: getting TCPDUMP output but not showing on loganalyzer



[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump | grep 10.50.56.65
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
12:11:19.231872 IP 10.50.56.65.btpp2sectrans > 10.50.55.110.syslog: SYSLOG local7.notice, length: 485
12:11:19.234294 IP 10.50.56.65.btpp2sectrans > 10.50.55.110.syslog: SYSLOG local7.warning, length: 756
12:11:19.237968 IP 10.50.56.65.bt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please verify that whichever firewall you are using is setup to allow incoming traffic on port 514 over both UDP and TCP traffic? If so, then *temporarily* disable SELinux and try again.

Comment: how can i do that. i mean what is the command to disable. \n Moreover i have stopped iptables service **service iptables stop**

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled


but still not receiving logs